# Can I pass an F() expression value into my own function and still call update in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to convert a bunch of fields on a certain Django (1.9) model from string to decimals.  Instead of doing this:

```
for x in Foo.objects.all():
    x.biz = str_to_decimal(x.bar)
    x.bang = str_to_decimal(x.fizz)
    ...
    x.save()
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
fields = {
    'biz': str_to_decimal(models.F('bar')),
    'bang': str_to_decimal(models.F('fizz')),
   }

Foo.objects.update(**fields)
```

The bulk update functionality isn't available to me either since it's only in a later version of Django. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: No, since the update is done at the database side, and Django will not know how to "encode" `str_to_decimal` to an SQL expression.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using that doesn't have the update method?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - OK that's what I thought, I just didn't know if there was anything else I could do. Thank you. @Iain Shlvington - Django doesn't have bulk_update before version 2.2. I could have at least updated my fields and used that instead of `save()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Cast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function to cast fields to another type

```
Foo.objects.update(
   biz=Cast(models.F('bar'), output_field=models.DecimalField()),
   bang=Cast(models.F('fizz'), output_field=models.DecimalField())
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can use Cast for some of them, but some are special characters that we need to handle separately from Cast. Thanks!

Comment: Give examples of the special characters and maybe I can suggest some other functions to use

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said characters. We have some string values like '1-1/4"' that need converted to 1.25